# Anyone tried getting netatalk working on elementary os?

Tags: pantheon-files, settings, files, filesystem, samba

Just wondering since this os mimics Apple. I know that Apple may be doing away with afp, but they haven't yet and it will works. If elementary is is based on Ubuntu, can I just use netatalk 'a instructions for Ubuntu?

Comment: I haven't tried it by I see no reason why installing an AFP server on elementaryos would not work exactly as on Ubuntu.  Files will connect and browse AFP shares running on an Ubuntu based server successfully (at least in Loki it will).

Answer (score 1):

yes.

```
sudo apt install netatalk
```

I am currently using Pantheon with netatalk for file sharing and Time Machine